# Does GWT have a Paragraph widget?

Tags: gwt, widget

I've drawn a blank. Does GWT have a widget that produces the HTML P tag?

I want just the P tag to appear in the DOM, without any extraneous DIV's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need a paragraph widget which can contain other widgets, you can use a `FlowPanel`:

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel(ParagraphElement.TAG);
panel.add(otherWidget);
```

The [String-arg constructor](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html#FlowPanel(java.lang.String)) allows the use of any HTML tag, and since `FlowPanel` extends `ComplexPanel`, you can append any other widgets inside it.

Answer (score 16):

GWT doesn't have such a widget. But you can easily create one. The SimplePanel has a protected constructor which allows it to create a panel with any HTML tag. To create a panel with the P tag, simply extend the SimplePanel and create it with your own constructor:

```
  public class PPanel extends SimplePanel {
    public PPanel() {
      super(Document.get().createPElement());
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer Hilbrand. By making PPanel also implement HasText, I have the solution I was seeking.

Comment: As on update with current GWT the `super` constructor call would now be: `super(DOM.createElement("p"));`

Comment: @checketts Actually using the `DOM` class is old-style GWT.

Comment: Thanks Hildebrand. I'd tried to use the example code snippet but the `.cast()` and the `(Element)` cast had given me trouble (though in hindsight I see what I had been doing wrong). 

I stripped out the extra casts and it also worked.  `super( Document.get().createPElement());`

Comment: I removed the `.cast()` call and `(Element)` cast; it does work without them. Thanks for the note @checketts.

Comment: @HilbrandBouwkamp Hey I modified your answer and posted it below. Yours is and should be the correct answer, but it might benefit from the addition I made. If you want to add the non-default constructor version to your answer I'd be happy to delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [HTMLPanel](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.6/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/HTMLPanel.html) widget?

Comment: I believe that HTMLPanel renders a DIV element, not a P element.

Comment: HTMLPanel has the constructor HTMLPanel(String tag,String html) so it can be any element

Answer (score 2):

Not to undermine Hilbrand Bouwkamp's answer, because it's where I derived mine from, I think a possibly more useful version of this is one that takes a string in the constructor. Hilbrand, if you just want to add this to your answer feel free and I will delete this answer.

```
public class PPanel extends SimplePanel {
    public PPanel() {
        super(Document.get().createPElement());
    }

    public PPanel(String string) {
        super(Document.get().createPElement());
        getElement().setInnerText(string);
    }
}
```

This way, rather than having to call:

```
PPanel panel = new PPanel();
panel.getElement().setInnerText("Text Here");
```

We can simply call:

```
PPanel panel = new PPanel("Text Here");
```

Answer (score 0):

GWT now has the PreElement along with all the other elements in a similar fashion.